# How to find maximum/minimum in `ContourPlot`?

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

The `ContourPlot` of `Sin[x^3 + y] - 2 Cos[x y]==0` has a maximum around `(-1.8,-2.3)`, see figure below. Is it possible to find it using for example `FindRoot`?

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x^3 + y] - 2 Cos[x y] == 0, {x, -2, -1}, {y, -4, -2}, 
Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{-1.8, -2.35}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also post-process `ContourPlot` output to add to each `Line` its peak point(s):

```
ClearAll[addPeaks]
addPeaks = Normal[#] /. l:Line[x_, ___] :> {l, PointSize[Large], Point@MaximalBy[x, Last]}&
```

**Examples:**

```
addPeaks @ ContourPlot[Sin[x^3 + y] - 2 Cos[x y] == 0, {x, -2, -1}, {y, -4, -2}]
```

[image]

```
addPeaks @ ContourPlot[Evaluate[Sum[Sin[RandomReal[5, 2].{x, y}], {4}]], 
  {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
  Contours -> 5, ContourStyle -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[5]), 
  ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and elegant. Would you know how to remove  the 'edge points' (on axis) generically too?

Comment: @chris, easiest/laziest way i can think of is to post-process: if `cp = addPeaks @ContourPlot ...` then  define a  pattern for points on the border using `PlotRange[cp]`, i.e. `borderpnts = Alternatives @@ (Point[{#}] & /@ 
     Join @@ ({#, Reverse /@ #2} & @@ (Thread /@ Thread[{PlotRange[cp], Blank[]}])));` then use `DeleteCases[cp, borderpnts, {0, Infinity}]`

Comment: Thanks for this

Answer (score 6):

Writing:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x^3 + y] - 2 Cos[x y]

conditions = {f[x, y] == 0, -D[f[x, y], x]/D[f[x, y], y] == 0};

sol = FindRoot[conditions, {x, -2}, {y, -2}, WorkingPrecision -> 10][[All, 2]]

ContourPlot[Evaluate[conditions[[1]]], {x, -2, -1}, {y, -4, -2}, 
            Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[sol]}]
```

I get:

> {-1.812103489, -2.341140661}
>
> [image]

which is what is desired.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks @TeM

Comment: Just one more thing, assume that f(x,y) is a very complex function, in this case is it possible to evaluate the conditions numerically?

Answer (score 6):

Just an alternative without `FindRoot` using `MeshFunction`

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x^3 + y] - 2 Cos[x y]
ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -2, -1}, {y, -4, -2}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
MeshStyle -> Red, MeshFunctions ->Function[{x, y}, Derivative[1, 0][f][x,y]/Derivative[0, 1][f][x, y]]]
```

[image]

This version finds all the extrema!

Answer (score 2):

`NMaximize` according to `y`.

```
sol = NMaximize[{y, 
    Sin[x^3 + y] - 2 Cos[x y] == 0, -2 < x < -1, -4 < y < -2}, {x, y}];
pt = {x, y} /. sol[[2]]
ContourPlot[Sin[x^3 + y] - 2 Cos[x y] == 0, {x, -2, -1}, {y, -4, -2}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pt]}]
```

> `{-1.8121, -2.34114}`

[image]